# What's the proper way to say "1 unit of caviar"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, idiomatic-language

What's the proper way to say "1 unit of caviar"? Caviar is an uncountable noun even though technically it's countable unlike water, so because of that I am not sure if you can refer to "1 unit of caviar" idiomatically. Is it the case? I thought about "1 egg of caviar", "1 unit of caviar", but they sound really weird and unidiomatic. How would you say it?

For example:

> He took 1 unit of caviar and put it on top of a rice ball just to show
>   him he was a frugal chef.

Comment: by "1 unit" do you want to mean exactly 1 egg? or just a small amount of caviar?

Comment: I mean exactly 1 egg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading this [caviar website](https://www.caviar.bc.ca/caviar-glossary-of-terms/) it seems that **beads** or **pearls** would be an appropriate way to refer to a caviar egg.

> He took one caviar pearl and put it on top of a rice ball just to show him he was a frugal chef.

Answer (score 1):

Caviar comes in tin cans, so we usually say *one tin* or *one can of caviar,* just like we say *one can of tuna.*

If you use ctrl+F on [this page](https://www.seriouseats.com/2013/02/the-serious-eats-guide-to-how-to-buy-caviar.html), you'll see people using both *tin* and *can.*

If you are looking for the word for individual eggs, the most conversational thing to say would be just that: *one caviar egg.*

Another answer cites the word *pearl* found on a culinary blog. This sounds like restaurantese to me: the writer chose a beautiful, spherical, and nautical object to highlight caviar's luxurious image. Ditto for *bead.* I would choose one of these words if you are writing with the intent of making the caviar sound delicious, e.g. promotional copy or a restaurant menu.